# "Летающее" активити поверх всех приложений

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечерок, друзья. Кто-нибудь знает как можно реализовать активити, которое будет находится поверх всего на экране? Нужно что-то вроде мгновенного перевода в Google Translate. В интернете никакой инфы не нашёл. Может у этого явления есть своё название?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вы имеете ввиду alert dialog?

Comment: Я думаю, что речь о `Floating Action Button` :)

Comment: Нет, Floating Action Button - это совсем другое. Нужно активити, которое будет появляться поверх любого приложения. Я же приводил в пример Google Translate. При копировании текста там выскакивает кнопочка сверху справа.

Comment: Специально скачал google translate, чтобы посмотреть что же там за летающее активити. Скорее всего, там одно единственное активити, в котором несколько фрагментов. К фрагментам применена анимация появления/исчезновения и передвижения на местр тулбара

Comment: я так полагаю Виталий хочет реализовать вьюшку, которая будет всегда находиться на экране даже если пользователь открыл другое приложение. Нечто подобное было (есть) в Мессенджере фейсбука, когда на экране всплывал контакт (вьюшка 48 на 48 dp) и ее можно было таскать в любое место, при этому она всегда назойливо висело поверх всех окон..

Comment: Chaynik, да, именно это мне и нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы наверное ищете что-то вроде [AppFloater](https://github.com/JustinScott/AppFloater)

> An Android app that creates an 'always on top' floating icon for any, non-system, installed application. Similar to the Facebook app chat heads. Makes use of my Floater library. Clicking the icon opens the package's default start activity. The icons are movable.